# Git - Completely ignore file

Tags: git

Someone in my organization committed .idea files.  I know the right answer is to just remove these, but I have to work around it as removing it will affect other developers workflow, and even though I disagree, I can not remove it from git at this time.

I am aware that I can stash and pop, and did that for a while, but constantly committing files from .idea on accident, and I'm just tired of having to amend my commits.

So I am trying to get git to completely ignore files in this folder, specifically `.idea/modules.xml`

I've tried the following:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged .idea/modules.xml
git update-index --skip-worktree .idea/modules.xml
```

Which makes the experience slightly better, the files no longer show up on git status, and I can use `git commit -am` without accidentally committing changes to idea files.

However, I am still getting an error when I try to pull.

```
git pull origin --rebase
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
.idea/modules.xml
```

Which I find odd, because git can't even find the file if I try to check it out:

```
git checkout .idea/modules.xml
error: pathspec '.idea/modules.xml' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I'm using the latest version of git from Homebrew

```
git --version
git version 2.13.3
```

Is this a bug in Git?  Is there some other configuration option I can use to just ignore this file completely?

Comment: `.gitignore`?  Or did you already consider that?

Comment: Can you tell your Idea to write its files into a different directory, so that you never modify the ones that are in Git?

Comment: `.gitignore` won't help with files that are committed and tracked already. It just prevents you from `git-add`ing them.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the history of the project discarding them... but that's just me. I don't want stuff that doesn't belong into the project to be there... specially if it's *relatively* easy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To completely stop tracking a file you need to remove it from the index. This can be done with this command.

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

The removal of the file from the head revision will happen on the next commit.

Comment: That is what I was saying in my own answer: -1. Plus the OP clearly indicated this is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

> I know the right answer is to just remove these, but I have to work around it

You don't have to work around it: record its deletion:

```
git rm --cached -r .idea/
echo ".idea/" >> .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "remove .idea/ folder"
git push
```

From there on, no more `.idea` folder in your repo.

> Removing the folder is not an option. It is used for developers workflows and currently no matter how much I disagree it has to stay there.

Then rename it:

```
git mv .idea .idea_settings
echo ".idea/" >> .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "rename .idea/ folder"
git push
```

- any user wanting to use those settings can symlink it.

  ```
  ln -s .idea .idea_symlink
  ```
- any user who don't want to use it will keep a private  untracked `.idea`

Comment: Removing the folder is not an option.  It is used for developers workflows and currently no matter how much I disagree it has to stay there.  Which is why I said I have to work around it, for now.

Comment: @AlexSpence I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @AlexSpence Any chance my alternative proposal might have helped?